# How to fill the QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some code, where i try to fill the QTableWidget. But when I run this application the sells are empty. I checked whether contains QTableWidget any elements(items), it`s contains.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QTableWidget *pWidget = new QTableWidget( 5, 6 );

    for( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
    {
        for( int column = 0; column < 6; column++ )
        {
            QString sItem = QString::number( row + column );

            QVariant oVariant(sItem);

            QTableWidgetItem oItem;
            oItem.setData( Qt::DisplayRole, oVariant );
            pWidget->setItem( row, column, &oItem );

            QVariant oData = pWidget->item( row, column )->data( Qt::DisplayRole );
            qDebug() << "OData: " << oData.toString();
        }
    }

    QTimer::singleShot( 0, pWidget, SLOT( show() ) );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkqZW.jpg)

Comment: allocate the table item in the heap `QTableWidgetItem * poItem = new QTableWidgetItem();`

Comment: @eyllanesc Why? Does this constructor  QTableWidget( 5, 6 ) not work correctly?

Comment: @eyllanesc No  I do not have used Qt Disagner. I want to use only code.

Comment: @eyllanesc In Qt Designer I use only Button, which calls SLOT on_pushButton_clicked()

Comment: @eyllanesc I need to call asyncronious with singleShot()

Comment: @Simon I tryed to allocate QTableWidgetItem * poItem = new QTableWidgetItem(); it does not helped

Comment: I tested your code with the item allocation on my project and it works. `QTableWidgetItem * poItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
               poItem->setData( Qt::DisplayRole, oVariant );
               pWidget->setItem( row, column, poItem );`

Comment: @Simon Sorry. QTableWidgetItem * poItem = new QTableWidgetItem() Its work! Can you create answer!?

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин, I post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate the `QTableWidgetItem`

working example:

```
QTableWidget *pWidget = new QTableWidget( 5, 6 );

for( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
{
    for( int column = 0; column < 6; column++ )
    {
        QString sItem = QString::number( row + column );

        QVariant oVariant(sItem);

        // allocate the widget item
        QTableWidgetItem * poItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
        poItem->setData( Qt::DisplayRole, oVariant );
        pWidget->setItem( row, column, poItem );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt5 it looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# Creates an Qt item
qt_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(CELL_DATA) 

# Set the qt_item at position (row, column) of your table_widget
table_widget.setItem(row, column, qt_item)
```